# Does AWS AppSync have limits definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

When I use API Gateway, I can find the limits from this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

One of the big limits for websocket is 2 hours duration time. Because of that, I am going to use App sync with websocket connection but I can't find any limits on that. Does AWS release any limits for AppSync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [service quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/appsync.html) for AppSync can be found in the link.

Comment: I have read it but it doesn't have duration time limit. Does it mean it support connection forever?

Comment: Hi, there should be no time limit.